# Inferring the return type of typescript function from the returned value

Tags: typescript

Consider this example:

```js
type State = { sth: Something };
type Selector = <T>(state: State) => T;
const selector: Selector = state => state.sth;
```

I want the return type of the `selector` function to be inferred automatically from the returned value and also be able to access its properties, but I get this error:

`Type 'Something' is not assignable to Type 'T'`

Is it possible to do this without explicitly specifying the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Selector` is a generic function, as such any implementation of it should be a generic function.

You probably want `Selector` to be a generic type, that happens to be a function:

```
type Selector<T> = (state: State) => T;
```

This would let you wrote something like:

```
const selector: Selector<Something> = state => state.sth;
```

This still does not have the exact behavior you want though as you need to be explict about the type of the variable.

Typescript has no syntax for partial variable type inference, (somthing like `const selector: Selector<?>`). Variable type inference is an all or nothing affair, you either get the type of the initialization expression, or you are fully explicit about the type.

I would urge you to consider if you really need an explicit annotation. IF you let TS infer `selector` in an expression such as (`const selector = (state: State) => state.sth`) it would be `(state: State) => Something`, which would be compatible (essentially the same) with `Selector<Something>`. So if you were to use `selector` in a place where `Selector<Something>` is expected you would get an error if the function does not return `Something`

If you want to infer `Selector<Something>` for `selector` the only vehicle we have for inference is a function, so you could define a generic function will infer the appropriate `T`

```
type Something  =  { s: string}
type State = { sth: Something };
type Selector<T> = (state: State) => T;
function createSelector<T>(fn: Selector<T>) {
    return fn
}
const selector = createSelector(state => state.sth);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=53&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMpQLy4DeUAzgFynABOmWAvgLABQokswAhsNAcSahXhJUtKHQDczVtBgQANhADGwOFQA8AFQB8+KAAp+XCIM7cAlPh0bJTAGYBXDMrRwMURVQhHZC5as1aerYYgvJKKuraFoTMuLiewPZUbsHMjEyKrvykYX5Uuh5e3D7hqgamPDqG3AB0-Chm4kA)